# how do we write a function that outputs the solution to an equation?

Tags: notation

I want to define a function abstractly, rather than directly. 
So I want to define a function $f(r)$ as the value of $x$ for which the equation $g(x,r)=0$, for example.

**I'd like to do this without words. Is there a generally accepted notation to define this function?** e.g. it could look something like:

$$f(r)=Solve_x(g(x,r)=0)$$
Or something like that.

Comment: The equation may have more than one solution; consider as $g(x,1)=0$ the equation $(x-1)(x+1)=0$. In this case $f(1)$ is not a function.

Comment: I know but that would just mean that $f$ is undefined at certain values of x. That can happen with any function.

Comment: $f(r)=y \leftrightarrow \exists ! z \ [g(z,r)=0 \land y=z]$ with an extra condition (like e.g. $f(r)=0$) or undefined when the eistence and uniqueness condition is not satisfied.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use words? If you are doing something abstractly then communication of the idea should be key.

Comment: Its often more succinct and easier to read. The same way an explicit function is easier to read than an implicit one.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like

> Define $f$ by
>
> $$g(f(r),r)=0$$

but you should be careful to check that such a function actually can be defined. For example if $g(x,r)$ was $x^2+r^2-1$ then it would be unclear what $f$ was supposed to be, because there's more than one possible $x$ for each $r$.

Comment: Is there no way to get rid of the "Define $f$ by", and put it into a single neat expression?

Comment: Sure, just delete "Define $f$ by". It'll be less clear but that's the price of not using words.

Comment: So your answer is "no"

Answer (score 0):

*If* you've told the reader at the beginning that you'll be using a certain notation (e.g. $:=$) for definitions *and* you've established the convention that you don't care about codomains (that a function is just its corresponding graph/relation) *and* there is always a unique solution to your equation, you could write something like the following:

$f:=\{(r,s)\mid g(s,r)=0\} $

I would not recommend this method. Words are used in math to make things more readable.